# How to use integer RowKeys in Azure Table Storage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I have consecutively numbered entities that I want to persist with the Azure Table Service, however the type of the RowKey column is problematic.
The number of the entity should be stored in the RowKey column, so I can query entities fast (`PK = '..' && RowKey = 5`), get newest entities (`RowKey > 10`) and query a certain set of entities (`RowKey > 5 && RowKey < 10`).

Since RowKey must be a string, lower-than comparisons are problematic (`"100" < "11"`).
I thought about prepending zeros to the numbers (so that `"100" > "011"`), but I can't predict the number of entities (and thus the number of zeros).

I know I could just create an integer column, but I would loose the performance advantage of the indexed RowKey column (plus I don't have any other information suitable for RowKey). 
Did anyone have this problem before?

Comment: Just call x.ToString("X8") for positive numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar problem, with the added caveat that I also wanted to support having the RowKey sorted in descending order.  In my case I did not care about supporting trillions of possible values because I was correctly using the PartitionKey and also using scoping prefixes when needed to further segment the RowKey (like "scope-id" -> "12-8374").

In the end I settled on an specific implementation of the general approach suggested by enzi.  I used a modified version of Base64 encoding, producing a four character string, which supports over 16 million values and can be sorted in ascending or descending order.  Here is the code, which has been unit tested but lacks range checking/validation.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Gets the four character string representation of the specified integer id.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="number">The number to convert</param>
/// <param name="ascending">Indicates whether the encoded number will be sorted ascending or descending</param>
/// <returns>The encoded string representation of the number</returns>
public static string NumberToId(int number, bool ascending = true)
{
    if (!ascending)
        number = 16777215 - number;

    return new string(new[] { 
        SixBitToChar((byte)((number & 16515072) >> 18)), 
        SixBitToChar((byte)((number & 258048) >> 12)), 
        SixBitToChar((byte)((number & 4032) >> 6)), 
        SixBitToChar((byte)(number & 63)) });
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the numeric identifier represented by the encoded string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The encoded string to convert</param>
/// <param name="ascending">Indicates whether the encoded number is sorted ascending or descending</param>
/// <returns>The decoded integer id</returns>
public static int IdToNumber(string id, bool ascending = true)
{
    var number = ((int)CharToSixBit(id[0]) << 18) | ((int)CharToSixBit(id[1]) << 12) | ((int)CharToSixBit(id[2]) << 6) | (int)CharToSixBit(id[3]);

    return ascending ? number : -1 * (number - 16777215);
}

/// <summary>
/// Converts the specified byte (representing 6 bits) to the correct character representation.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="b">The bits to convert</param>
/// <returns>The encoded character value</returns>
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] 
static char SixBitToChar(byte b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return '!';
    if (b == 1)
        return '$';
    if (b < 12)
        return (char)((int)b - 2 + (int)'0');
    if (b < 38)
        return (char)((int)b - 12 + (int)'A');
    return (char)((int)b - 38 + (int)'a');
}

/// <summary>
/// Coverts the specified encoded character into the corresponding bit representation.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="c">The encoded character to convert</param>
/// <returns>The bit representation of the character</returns>
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] 
static byte CharToSixBit(char c)
{
    if (c == '!')
        return 0;
    if (c == '$')
        return 1;
    if (c <= '9')
        return (byte)((int)c - (int)'0' + 2);
    if (c <= 'Z')
        return (byte)((int)c - (int)'A' + 12);
    return (byte)((int)c - (int)'a' + 38);
}
```

You can just pass false to the ascending parameter to ensure the encoded value will sort in the opposite direction.  I selected ! and $ to complete the Base64 set since they are valid for RowKey values.  This algorithm can be easily amended to support additional characters, though I firmly believe that larger numbers do not make sense for RowKey values as table storage keys must be efficiently segmented.  Here are some examples of output:

0 -> !!!! asc & zzzz desc

1000 -> !!Dc asc & zzkL desc

2000 -> !!TE asc & zzUj desc

3000 -> !!is asc & zzF5 desc

4000 -> !!yU asc & zz$T desc

5000 -> !$C6 asc & zylr desc

6000 -> !$Rk asc & zyWD desc

7000 -> !$hM asc & zyGb desc

8000 -> !$x! asc & zy0z desc

9000 -> !0Ac asc & zxnL desc

Answer (score 2):

I found an easy way but the previous solution is more efficient (regarding key length).
Instead of using all alphabets we can use just the numbers and the key is to make the length fixed (0000,0001,0002,.....):

```
public class ReadingEntity : TableEntity
{
    public static string KeyLength = "000000000000000000000";
    public ReadingEntity(string partitionId, int keyId)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = partitionId;
        this.RowKey = keyId.ToString(KeyLength); ;


    }
    public ReadingEntity()
    {
    }
}


public IList<ReadingEntity> Get(string partitionName,int date,int enddate)
{
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        // Create the CloudTable object that represents the "people" table.
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Record");

        // Construct the query operation for all customer entities where PartitionKey="Smith".
        TableQuery<ReadingEntity> query = new TableQuery<ReadingEntity>().Where(TableQuery.CombineFilters(
    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionName),
    TableOperators.And,TableQuery.CombineFilters(
    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.LessThan, enddate.ToString(ReadingEntity.KeyLength)), TableOperators.And,
    TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, date.ToString(ReadingEntity.KeyLength)))));
        return table.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can post-append a guid to an integer. that should help with sorts.
http://blogs.southworks.net/fboerr/2010/04/22/compsition-in-windows-azure-table-storage-choosing-the-row-key-and-simulating-startswith/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a custom `RowKey` class that wraps around a String and provides an `Increment` method.

I can now define a range of valid characters (e.g. `0-9 + a-z + A-Z`) and "count" within this range (e.g. `az9 + 1 = aza`, `azZ + 1 = aA0`). The advantage of this compared to using only numbers is that I have a far greater range of possible keys (`62^n`instead of `10^n`).

I still have to define the length of the string beforehand and mustn't change it, but now I can store pretty much any number of entities while keeping the string itself much shorter. For example, with 10 digits I can store `~8*10^17` keys and with 20 digits `~7*10^35`.

The number of valid characters can of course be increased further to use the number of digits even more effectively, but in my case the above range was sufficient and is still readable enough for debugging purposes.

I hope this answer helps others who run into the same problem.

EDIT: Just as a side note in case anyone wants to implement something similar: You will have to create custom character ranges and can't just count from 0 upwards, because there are illegal characters (e.g. `/`, `\`) between the numbers (`0-9`) and the lowercase letters.

Answer (score -1):

I found a potential solution if you're using [Linq to query against Azure Table Storage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/01/06/walkthrough-windows-azure-table-storage-nov-2009-and-later.aspx).

You add something like this to your model for the table...

```
public int ID 
{
    get
    {
        return int.Parse(RowKey);
    }
}
```

And then you can do this in your Linq query...

```
.Where(e => e.ID > 1 && e.ID < 10);
```

With this technique you're not actually adding the "ID" column to the table since it has no "set" operation in it.

The one thing I'm unsure about is what's happening behind the scenes exactly.  I want to know what the query to Azure Table Storage looks like in its final form, but I'm not sure how to find that out.  I haven't been able to find that information when debugging and using quickwatch.

UPDATE

I still haven't figured out what's happening, but I have a strong feeling that this isn't very efficient.  I'm thinking the way to go is to create a [sortable string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807111/whats-the-best-way-to-represent-system-double-as-a-sortable-string) as the OP did.  Then you can use the `RowKey.CompareTo()` function in your Linq where clause to filter by a range.