# What's the best way to represent System.Double as a sortable string?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, double

In data formats where all underlying types are strings, numeric types must be converted to a standardized string format which can be compared alphabetically. For example, a `short` for the value `27` could be represented as `00027` if there are no negatives.

What's the best way to represent a `double` as a string? In my case I can ignore negatives, but I'd be curious how you'd represent the double in either case.

**UPDATE**

Based on Jon Skeet's suggestion, I'm now using this, though I'm not 100% sure it'll work correctly:

```
static readonly string UlongFormatString = new string('0', ulong.MaxValue.ToString().Length);

public static string ToSortableString(this double n)
{
    return BitConverter.ToUInt64(BitConverter.GetBytes(BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(n)), 0).ToString(UlongFormatString);
}

public static double DoubleFromSortableString(this string n)
{
    return BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(BitConverter.ToInt64(BitConverter.GetBytes(ulong.Parse(n)), 0));
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have confirmed what Jon suspected - negatives don't work using this method. Here is some sample code:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = double.MaxValue;
    var b = double.MaxValue/2;
    var c = 0d;
    var d = double.MinValue/2;
    var e = double.MinValue;
    Console.WriteLine(a.ToSortableString());
    Console.WriteLine(b.ToSortableString());
    Console.WriteLine(c.ToSortableString());
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToSortableString());
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToSortableString());
}

static class Test
{
    static readonly string UlongFormatString = new string('0', ulong.MaxValue.ToString().Length);
    public static string ToSortableString(this double n)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToUInt64(BitConverter.GetBytes(BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(n)), 0).ToString(UlongFormatString);
    }
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
09218868437227405311
09214364837600034815
00000000000000000000
18437736874454810623
18442240474082181119
```

Clearly not sorted as expected.

**UPDATE 3**

The accepted answer below is the correct one. Thanks guys!

Comment: Why do you want to sort strings (= representations) rather than the real values? This is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @Konrad I explained this in the question - "where all underlying types are strings". Specifically in my case, I'm using Lucene, but there are other formats where alphabetical sorting is required too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Padding is potentially rather awkward for doubles, given the enormous range (`double.MaxValue` is 1.7976931348623157E+308).

Does the string representation still have to be human-readable, or just reversible?

That gives a reversible conversion leading to a reasonably short string representation preserving lexicographic ordering - but it wouldn't be at all obvious what the `double` value was just from the string.

EDIT: *Don't* use `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits` alone. That reverses the ordering for negative values.

I'm sure you *can* perform this conversion using `DoubleToInt64Bits` and then some bit-twiddling, but unfortunately I can't get it to work *right now*, and I have three kids who are desperate to go to the park...

---

In order to make everything sort correctly, negative numbers need to be stored in ones-complement format instead of sign magnitude (otherwise negatives and positives sort in opposite orders), and the sign bit needs to be flipped (to make negative sort less-than positives).  This code should do the trick:

```
static ulong EncodeDouble(double d)
{
    long ieee = System.BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d);
    ulong widezero = 0;
    return ((ieee < 0)? widezero: ((~widezero) >> 1)) ^ (ulong)~ieee;
}

static double DecodeDouble(ulong lex)
{
    ulong widezero = 0;
    long ieee = (long)(((0 <= (long)lex)? widezero: ((~widezero) >> 1)) ^ ~lex);
    return System.BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(ieee);
}
```

Demonstration here: http://ideone.com/JPNPY

Here's the complete solution, to and from strings:

```
static string EncodeDouble(double d)
{
    long ieee = System.BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d);
    ulong widezero = 0;
    ulong lex = ((ieee < 0)? widezero: ((~widezero) >> 1)) ^ (ulong)~ieee;
    return lex.ToString("X16");
}

static double DecodeDouble(string s)
{
    ulong lex = ulong.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    ulong widezero = 0;
    long ieee = (long)(((0 <= (long)lex)? widezero: ((~widezero) >> 1)) ^ ~lex);
    return System.BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(ieee);
}
```

Demonstration: http://ideone.com/pFciY

Comment: I know the question said it was ok to not handle negatives, but it's worth mentioning them in your answer anyway, for the next reader who comes along.  One may of course append a human-readable representation to a Base64 (or similar) encoding of the raw bits.

Comment: @Ben: I don't think they're affected really - if you've got a string format which handles negative Int64 values, it will work fine for negative doubles too.

Comment: @Ben: Why? It should be fine, so long as your Int64 format is already a sortable one. In other words, it reduces to the problem of formatting all Int64 values in lexicographic order, including negative ones.

Comment: @Jon, that's a great answer - to be honest I'm not quite sure what the best way to represent negatives is considering both positive and negative extremes tend towards zero at the middle. I suppose I could convert to ulong and increment the value by long.MaxValue?

Comment: @Nathan: You'd want to subtract `long.MinValue` actually (so that that became 0). That's definitely an option - again, if you're happy with the representation not really being human-readable :)

Comment: @Jon: Sign-magnitude representation doesn't sort lexicographically.  Switching to one's complement wouldn't be difficult, but is a necessary additional step.  As an example, compare `-2` to `-3` using your method.

Comment: @Ben: I think you've still missed my point - I'm saying that the "convert doubles" problem can be reduced to "convert longs". I was treating the long conversion as out of scope for this question - Nathan's shown one way of doing it, and no doubt there are others. The point is that the double to long conversion task is separable from the long to string conversion task.

Comment: @Jon: I suppose, but you need a different long->string conversion for longs that came from doubles, since they need to be sorted by different rules than "true" longs (I was going to say "real", but then I "real"-ized that would be an unfortunate pun when trying to encode real numbers).

Comment: @Nathan: Please see my edit. Negative numbers won't work at the moment without a bit more effort.

Comment: I've updated my answer with what I suspect should work... although it may be flawed as I guess I'm assuming that the resultant output is in the correct order. In fact that might be a poor assumption after all...

Comment: @Ben: Cool. Are you happy to edit that into my answer? On a mobile right now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a modified scientific notation, with the exponent first, and using underscore for positive, would sort lexically in the same order as numerically.

If you want, you can even append the normal representation, since a suffix won't affect sorting.

Examples

```
E000M3    +3.0
E001M2.7  +27.0
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for either negative numbers or negative exponents.  You could introduce a bias for the exponent, like the IEEE format uses internally.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out... The org.apache.solr.util package contains the NumberUtils class. This class has static methods that do everything needed to convert doubles (and other data values) to sortable strings (and back). The methods could not be easier to use. A few notes:

1. Of course, NumberUtils is written in Java (not c#). My guess it that the code could be converted to c#... However, I am not well versed in c#. The source is readily available online.
2. The resulting strings are not printable (at all).
3. The comments in the code indicate that all exotic cases, including negative numbers and infinities, should work correctly.
4. I haven't done any benchmarks... However, based on a quick scan of the code, it should be very fast.

The code below shows what needs to done to use this library.

```
String key = NumberUtils.double2sortableStr(35.2);
```