# How can I represent System.Int64 as a lexically sortable string?

Tags: c#, sorting

I would like to convert (64-bit) integers to lexically sortable strings (i.e, I can sort the resulting strings with String.Compare, and get the same order that I would for directly comparing the original values). [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) provided an implementation for doubles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6807206/385094). I would like to do the same for **Int64** (also Int32, float, datetime, timespan, but I'm sure I can get there from Int64).

**How can I represent System.Int64 in C# as a lexically sortable string?**

I like that the linked implementation uses ASCII characters (it's hex-encoded), and is therefore vaguely human-presentable, if not strictly human-readable.

I'm looking for a method that works for all valid positive and negative values of Int64.

Here's a test that works for Jon Skeet's implementation of "EncodeDouble", along with implementations of each of those methods. My implementation is unchanged from the linked question, but provided for completeness.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void LexicallySortRandomDoubles()
    {
        var r = new Random(15245);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[16];
            r.NextBytes(bytes);
            var a = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, 0);
            var b = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes, 8);

            // don't sort equal values, or nans.
            if (double.IsInfinity(a) || double.IsNaN(a) || double.IsInfinity(b) || double.IsNaN(b)) continue;

            var c = LexicallySortableValues.EncodeDouble(a);
            var d = LexicallySortableValues.EncodeDouble(b);

            // Comparison works
            Assert.IsTrue(
                a < b == System.String.Compare(c, d, System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) < 0,
                string.Format("i={4}, a = {0}, b = {1}, c = {2}, d = {3}", a, b, c, d, i));
        }
    }

    public static ulong DoubleToSortableULong(double d)
    {
        long ieee = System.BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d);
        const ulong widezero = 0;
        return ((ieee < 0) ? widezero : ((~widezero) >> 1)) ^ (ulong)~ieee;
    }

    public static double SortableULongToDobule(ulong lex)
    {
        const ulong widezero = 0;
        long ieee = (long)(((0 <= (long)lex) ? widezero : ((~widezero) >> 1)) ^ ~lex);
        return System.BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(ieee);
    }

    public static string EncodeDouble(double d)
    {
        ulong lex = DoubleToSortableULong(d);
        return lex.ToString("X16");
    }

    public static double DecodeDouble(string s)
    {
        ulong lex = ulong.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        return SortableULongToDobule(lex);
    }
```

Comment: Would you mind adding question to your post?

Comment: ToString("D19") gets you there for positive values. I think you perhaps need to be a bit clearer on what your requirements are.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeiLevenkov I have addressed your comment.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan I have addressed your comment by stating that I wish to sort both positive and negative values of Int64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to deal with the signed nature of `Int64`, I suggest that you convert the signed 64 bit integer to an unsigned 64 bit value by adding `-Int64.MinValue`. Shifting preserves ordering and the shift value is chosen to ensure that the result is always representable in a `UInt64` variable.

Then format to 19 decimal digits with `ToString("D20")`. Or to 16 hex digits with `ToString("X16")`.

Implement the shift like this:

```
static UInt64 ShiftToUnsigned(Int64 sval)
{
    unchecked
    {
        return (UInt64) (sval - Int64.MinValue);
    }
}
```

And the conversion to string then can be:

```
static string LexicallySortable(Int64 value)
{
    return ShiftToUnsigned(value).ToString("X16");
}
```

And then this program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Compare(LexicallySortable(Int64.MinValue), LexicallySortable(-2)));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Compare(LexicallySortable(-2), LexicallySortable(-1)));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Compare(LexicallySortable(-1), LexicallySortable(0)));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Compare(LexicallySortable(0), LexicallySortable(1)));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Compare(LexicallySortable(1), LexicallySortable(Int64.MaxValue)));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

outputs a series of `-1` values as desired.

Comment: you are right, this is much easier than my solution. Perhaps one thing: you may want to wrap the Uint64 cast into `unchecked{}` to avoid errors if this is called from a `checked` context?

Comment: @Hugo I don't think there are checked errors here. At least not when I tried. Checked is the default isn't it? I'm not fluent in this part of C#. Thanks.

Comment: @HugoRune My lack of fluency is hurting me here. Yes, checking is off by default. You are of course right. I had originally thought that I would need `unchecked` but didn't dig deep enough. Thanks.

Comment: Good answer. If you don't like hex, just use leading decimal with leading zeroes. As an alternative to the subtraction trick you could prepend + and -.

Comment: @usr prepend leading zeros is covered by "D20" format in the answer. Also prepending +/- won't work because then -2 would be greater than -1.

Comment: I tested everything I could think of and this works well. [here's](http://pastebin.com/ALrgLWg4) my tests. Thanks @DavidHeffernan!